# How can I disable "git checkout" in Git 2.23?

Tags: git

Now that Git 2.23 is out with support for `git switch` and `git restore`, I want to retrain my muscle memory by preventing `git checkout` from working. How can I make `git checkout` output an error message and exit with a non-zero status?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a way to do what exactly what you're requesting.

Git doesn't allow you to override a built-in subcommand with an alias, and for good reason.  Other tooling you're using may use `git checkout` and allowing you to override it with something else would break all of that tooling.

You can, however, override the `git` command in your shell configuration such that it fails if the subcommand is `checkout`, like so:

```
git () {
    if [ "$1" = "checkout" ]
    then
        echo "Don't use checkout; use switch or restore." >&2
        return 1
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

As long as this is only loaded for interactive shells and not for non-interactive shells (such as scripting), this should work and shouldn't affect anything negatively.  How to do this in your shell of choice is left as an exercise since you haven't specified which one you're using.

Also, note the warnings in the manual pages that `git switch` and `git restore` are experimental and may change.

Comment: Note that in 2023 it no longer says they are experimental